# Mostrar Form sólo la primera vez que se abre la aplicación / vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que antes de mostrarse como tal, lanzará un diálogo (form) que preguntará si desea hacer una copia de seguridad.

El punto es que quiero que únicamente aparezca ese Form la primera vez que el usuario abra la aplicación. ¿Se puede hacer eso con My.Settings?

Comment: Quieres que se muestre 1 vez cada vez que se abre la aplicación o quieres que se abra una única vez del todo y que después aunque vuelvan a abrir la aplicación no muestre nuevamente el Form?

Comment: Sí, lo segundo, que se muestre una sóla vez y cuando se cierre y vuelva a abrir, entonces el mensaje ya no aparezca más

Answer (score 0):

puedes revisar este documento: [persistir configuración del usuario en visual basic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/how-to-persist-user-settings)